# Finding a ready-to-fly Taranis compatible, Eachine compatible, S4 compatible under 200€ drone

Tags: quadcopters, recommendations, ready-to-fly

**The question**
I'm looking for a drone under 200€, preferably 5" (as that's what I'm used to)  but other sizes are ok, that can be purchased/delivered to France, is compatible with a Taranis X7 and an Eachine EV800D. It needs to be as plug & play as possible because I'd rather have the opportunity to fly it at least once before spending another 10 hours Macgyvering the thing.

I have found some fairly interesting starter deals on getfpv.com:

- https://www.getfpv.com/iflight-cidora-sl5-e-5-fpv-racing-drone-pnp.html
  Only problem: according to the description I need to add a receiver which is, if I understood correctly, precisely what I couldn't get to work in my last build
- https://www.getfpv.com/emax-hawk-sport-5-pnp-brushless-fpv-drone-1700kv.html
  I can't determine if this one is compatible with the gear I already own.

**Why not buy a complete package ?:**
Because I already own the transmitter and the FPV goggles. And from what I understood the gear I got is decent enough, so I'd rather keep using.
plus I'm used to flying a sim with the Taranis so I'd rather keep it.

**The Context, ignore if you don't care why I'm looking for such a plug & play solution:**
Last year, after watching a few guys flying their quads, I decided to buy one. Having quite some experience with building computers and being pushed by the other guys to custom build it, I ordered a bunch of component (chosen by them) and bought some second hand from said friends. I got started building the drone and it was a mess. I had done soldering work a few years before but never had it required such precision so I messed up and burnt parts of my first FC. Replaced it, managed to solder everything, only to realize halfway through the build that I couldn't for the life of me pair the Taranis to the receiver and have no way to check if the Taranis is at fault for cheap. I did a lot of research, re-soldered using different connections, changed the settings in betaflight ... in the end I changed the receiver. Still the same problem, spent an other half dozen hours on it.
I spare you a whole lot more problems and research online...
conclusion: after a good 25 hours spent trying to get this drone working I got so frustrated that I put everything in a box and left it there.
note: during the year this group dissolved itself and I now have no contact with anyone that knows anything about quads, so I couldn't get help in building/troubleshooting anything.

Now, I want to fly, but I'd rather not have to build, flash & setup everything myself while going blind and with nobody to help me if need be. Thus, I'm looking for a ready-to-fly drone.

Comment: Are there standards for this area? I don't think price shopping and recommendations fit with the StackExchange experience. This is not a technical question or help, indeed it is rooted in subjectivity and the current market and also has localization issues. There are plenty of forums to ask questions like this one.

Comment: If you believe it should be so, you are welcome to close it. Coming from stack overflow, over there it would definitely have been closed in the blink of an eye but, the presence of a "recommendations" tag, the absence of downvotes and close votes makes me feel like this isn't as unwelcome as it would be on some other sites within the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I just read the "ask a question" rules and still find myself in a grey zone regarding the acceptability of my question. If you find a real answer regarding this topic, please let me know

Comment: @MathieuVIALES Right now, this is considered on topic. It’s a good question

Comment: thank you @Daniil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the Cidora SL5-E is a very good choice. What you need to look for is the "BNF" suffix in the description which stands for "Bind and Fly". In that case a receiver is already built in.
On the iflight website you can select this option.
If you have the choice, it's best to select the r-xsr because it comes with telemetry.

If you are browsing shops look for these acronyms:

BNF: Bind and Fly, you can pair it to your existing remote and goggles

PNP: Plug and Play, you install your own receiver

RTF: Ready to Fly: a complete kit with everything included such as remote and sometimes goggles.

Comment: To add to this, the OP is looking for a FRSKY Bind-and-Fly.

Unfortunately, I don't see the Cidora (SL5 or SL5-e) BNF in stock anywhere in the US. You can order from iFlight, but that will take a while to arrive. Anything on this page should be a BNF that works with the OP's hardware: https://www.getfpv.com/ready-to-fly-quadcopters/5-rtf-quadcopters.html?receiver_protocol=1247.

Also: given that the OP is in France, there's probably an EU-based vendor they can order from, but I'm not familiar with those at all.

Comment: Thank you, I've read the specs and will order this quad, or a variant, from an European provider later today.

Comment: For posterity's sake: I have received the quad. Flown it last weekend and I'm very satisfied ! Good advice, good device !